# Electron - shortcut for catching text from other programs

Tags: electron

I've developed a web app which helps you correct spelling mistakes in your text.

Now I've wrapped my web app in Electron and it is working great.

Now, I would like to know if it is possible to create a keyboard shortcut to capture text from other programs such as notepad/word etc.. and pass the text to my web app?

For example:

If the user opens notepad and types some text, then he should be able to press a keyboard shortcut and the electron should automatically select/catch that text and pass it to my web app.

If the answer is "no", can I use C# with electron? Maybe combine both electron and c# together in some way?

Comment: Here is how you register a [globalShortcut](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/global-shortcut.md) with electron

Comment: You've developed a spell checking app but didn't bother running it on your post.